# Using Any to check against a list in NHibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, nhibernate, ilist

I am trying to get all @events where that have a `FiscalYear.id` in`IList<int> years`.  I am using `any()` but it is throwing the following stacktrace error:

```
 Unrecognised method call: 
 System.Linq.Enumerable:Boolean Any[TSource](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TSource], System.Func`2[TSource,System.Boolean])
```

Any Ideas? Here is the code:

```
FindAllPaged(int eventTypeId, IList<int> aors, IList<int> years)
{

IList<Domain.Event> results =
    session.QueryOver<Event>()
      .Where(@event => !@event.IsDeleted && 
      @event.EventType.Id == eventTypeId &&
      years.Any(y => y == @event.FiscalYear.Id))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338641.aspx) method instead:

```
IList<Domain.Event> results = session
    .QueryOver<Event>()
    .Where(e => !@event.IsDeleted && 
        @event.EventType.Id == eventTypeId &&
        years.Contains(@event.FiscalYear.Id))
    .ToList();
```

Or build your restrictions the long way using `IsIn`:

```
IList<Domain.Event> results = session
    .QueryOver<Event>()
    .Where(e => !@event.IsDeleted && @event.EventType.Id == eventTypeId)
    .And(Restrictions.On<Event>(@event => @event.FiscalYear.Id)
                     .IsIn(years.ToArray()))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: got this error now: `The best overloaded method match for 'NHibernate.Criterion.Lambda.LambdaRestrictionBuilder.IsIn(System.Collections.ICollection)' has some invalid arguments `

Comment: @Mike Okay I was stumped for a while until realized that `List<T>` implements `ICollection`, but `IList<T>` does not. If you change your `years` parameter to a `List<int>` or an `int[]` or if you simply call `years.ToList()` or `years.ToArray()` it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to use a Linq method in `QueryOver`.  This isn't supported.  Try using the Linq provider instead:

```
FindAllPaged(int eventTypeId, IList<int> aors, IList<int> years)
{

IList<Domain.Event> results =
    session.Query<Event>()
      .Where(@event => !@event.IsDeleted && 
      @event.EventType.Id == eventTypeId &&
      years.Any(y => y == @event.FiscalYear.Id))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same exception message

> Unrecognised method call: 
>    System.Linq.Enumerable:Boolean Any[TSource](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TSource], System.Func`2[TSource,System.Boolean])

when using IqueryOver with Contains method

```
 Ex: 
var departmentTypesArray = criteria.DepartmentTypes.ToArray();
qover = qover.Where(p => departmentTypesArray.Contains(p.DepartmentType));
```

when i check the database, i don't have any records inside the table that i am making query.

when i changed my query with Restrictions, then it works for me

```
qover = qover.WhereRestrictionOn(p => .DepartmentType).IsIn(departmentTypesArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
IList<Domain.Event> results = session.QueryOver<Event>().ToList().FindAll(e => !e.IsDeleted && e.Id.Equals(eventTypeId) && years.Contains(e.FiscalYear.Id))
```